# Limit image file size; if bigger, then decrease file size with lossy compression/resizing/etc. for saving disk space

Tags: media

When the user uploads an image with a large file size, I would like to allow him/her doing this (not restricting the file size generally, because many users don't know how to resize an image by themselves), BUT after this, **I would like to decrease the file size of this image (the original file!) somehow to save disk space** (lossy compression/resizing/etc.).
My site is on a shared hosting, so unfortunately ImageMagick is not available.

This question is very closely related, but does not contain any detailed information about the specific solution: [How can I reduce the file sizes of the original versions of uploaded image files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69032/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-sizes-of-the-original-versions-of-uploaded-image-files)

I also found the [ImageAPI Optimize](https://drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize) module, which can solve the **optimization** of the image via the online [Yahoo! Smush.It](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/) service, but optimization is not a restriction for the file size.
There are some related topics about limiting the file size of an image on Stack Overflow and Super User too:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258634/how-to-resize-an-image-in-c-sharp-to-a-certain-hard-disk-size
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094064/how-to-resize-a-picture-to-a-specific-file-size
- https://superuser.com/questions/201440/batch-resize-jpeg-images-to-a-fixed-file-size/297029#297029

Is there a Drupal-based solution for this task?

If it's unaccomplishable or too complex, maybe I should use an integrated solution with http://www.jpegmini.com/, but I don't know any modules which solves this.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in functions will not do this.

You will have to write a hook for the form,  upload the image at the original large size and then use Imagemagick (or similar) to process the image.

I only suggest Imagemagick because it's got more tools than GD and you should be able to re-size the image in a loop, testing for filesize and resizing/re-compressing as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, _"My site is on a shared hosting, so unfortunately ImageMagick is not available."_ :( What alternative solutions would you suggest?