# Reducing file size of original images on server (browser crashing)

Tags: 7, media

**Problem**

I don't want to limit my users photo size on upload, I'd prefer to compress once it's been uploaded incase they don't know how to compress images. I've implemented the first suggestion from this question:

[How can I reduce the file sizes of the original versions of uploaded image files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69032/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-sizes-of-the-original-versions-of-uploaded-image-files/69034#69034)

However sometimes when I click to upload a photo the browser locks. I can't find a pattern but it didn't happen before. Is there something wrong with my code, some sort of memory issue I might be unaware of?

(Otherwise the crop and scale works correctly.)

**Set-Up**

I've got a custom module and I'm hooking into the four forms on my site where people can upload photos. Here's an example of one of the forms:

```
  function resizeimage_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //select the correct form
    if ($form_id == 'profile2_edit_school_form') {
     //check that the form has been edited
      if(array_key_exists('values', $form_state)){
       //if it's been edited, check if the profile banner has been edited
        if(array_key_exists(0 , $form_state['values']['profile_school']['field_school_banner']['und'])) {
        //if it has, call the resize function
          array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'resizeimage_scaleandcrop');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function resizeimage_scaleandcrop($form, $form_state) {
    //grab the image fid
    $imagefid = $form_state['values']['profile_school']['field_school_banner']['und']['0']['fid'];
    //use it to load the file object
    $imageobject = file_load($imagefid);
    //use the filepath to load the image
    $imagefilepath = $imageobject->uri;
    //load the image
    $image = image_load($imagefilepath);
    image_scale_and_crop($image, 700, 200); 
    image_save($image);
  }
```