# Unable to Get Image to Un-Cache

Tags: caching

I've replaced an image on my home page with another image. I've verified that the new image is there (with the same name as the old image). And it's the only copy. I've run cron and cleared caches multiple times but the old image is still showing!

I'm using the following modules:
Advagg
Global Redirect
Cache Expiration (File update set under File Actions)
Elysia Cron
Boost
Boost Crawler
HTTPRL
Metatag
Metatag: Views
XML Sitemap

Anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Are you using image styles to render the image? If so, this is probably a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/rebuild-images-from-image-style

Comment: You can right click on the website and choose inspect element to check have you change your image successfully.

Comment: have you tried clearing your browsers cache?

Comment: @FreeRadical it's not image styles because I'm just manually linking to the image from a block using the <img> tag.

Comment: @Geoff yes, I have. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, I don't know what the problem was. I tried everything I could think of (see above). So I just changed the name of the image in 'default/files' and changed the name of the file in the link to it in the block. Now it's showing correctly.