# How do you force Drupal to re-render images?

Tags: media, theming

I have an image style. It's defined as requiring images which are 60x60, however all of the images it's created are 500x500.

This is a screenshot of the image style definition:
https://monosnap.com/file/GEIcrx6kRjeHg1b9VoDnRSAFNLgXmJ

I would think that this image would be a tad smaller (pixelation is intentional):
https://monosnap.com/file/E6oUIF3rxZ3qtLRTcbgJPGwZUg0j1e

I was able to disable and re-enable the responsive images in `borealis` on one of the environments, and that re-generated the same image, but that did not work on this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to flush your image style cache, eg. with this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagestyleflush

See also this answer: [Rebuild images from image style](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/rebuild-images-from-image-style)