# Images are refering wrong path on node import

Tags: importing-exporting, nodes

i import a node in my site using paste code method. after imported some images are refering wrong path ("https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/test.png?itok=a2KPyReV"). but the image is inside of the below path ("https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/test.png")

Comment: What exactly is your "paste code method"?

Comment: i mean there is two option in node import one is upload file and past code.i used past code option to import a node.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong path belongs to an image derived from image cache. It's the default "large" image style defined in admin/config/media/image-styles. You can try to [rebuild the image cache](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/rebuild-images-from-image-style), but success depends a bit on your "paste code method" which i'm unfamiliar with...