# Why images are not getting update in frontend when updated manual in files directory?

Tags: caching, media

I'm facing issue with images cache on my d7 site. I have changed some images from **files directory and theme's directory manually with same names**. But I'm not able to see in front end.Old images are still there. I tried all cache clear,cron run and theme registery clear.

Please help!

Comment: Have you clear your navigator cache ?

Comment: Try this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12950/7086

Comment: @Volker I manually deleted the file and executed this **drush image-flush** and image is deleted from server but its displaying in frontend.I have setup varnish on my site and cleared varnish cache. I'm shocked how its not getting work.
Any idea guys?

Comment: @kevin i cleared browser cache and all.